# Push values to array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push the values of my inputs to an array on click. For some reason it is not working.  The ".num1,.num2 etc refer to input id's.  I am getting an error submitValues not defined when I have defined it in the function?

```
$(function(){     
  Game.setup();
}); 

Game.setup = function(){
    Game.check();
}

// Setting up event listeners
Game.check = function(){
    $("#submit").on("click",submitValues);
}

Game.submitValues = function(){
    var playerGo = [];
    var num1 = $("num1");
    var num2 = $(".num2");
    var num3 = $(".num3");
    var num4 = $(".num4");
    playerGo.push(parseInt(num1,num2,num3,num4));
    console.log(playerGo);
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What results are you getting?

Comment: You may want to look into Number() instead of parseInt, see if it works. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp

Comment: What are num1-4 in relation to your inputs? Are they the class names? If so, num1 should be .num1. If you're using jquery, use .val() to get the input value too.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your calls to ParseInt:

```
playerGo.push(parseInt(num1,10));
playerGo.push(parseInt(num2,10));
playerGo.push(parseInt(num3,10));
playerGo.push(parseInt(num4,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems here

You need to address the contents of the elements you picked with the selectors, like `$('.num2').val()` for instance

Also, you need to fix one of your selectors: `num1` should be `.num1`.

And finally, `parseInt` only takes 2 arguments, the value and the radix (the base, 10 here).

I'd say it should look like this in the end

```
Game.submitValues = function () {
    var playerGo = [];
    var num1 = $(".num1").val();
    var num2 = $(".num2").val();
    var num3 = $(".num3").val();
    var num4 = $(".num4").val();

    playerGo.push(num1, num2, num3, num4);

    playerGo = playerGo.map(function (num) {
        return parseInt(num, 10);
    });

    console.log(playerGo);

    return playerGo;
}
```